# Cloud / Grid Computing Process Controller

Tags: .net, windows, grid, cloud

We have a set of ~10-15 windows desktops that we use for various grid computing tasks (crunching data, running optimizations etc), and I find myself constantly writing scripts / manually updating each computer with new versions of various grid applications that I am running.

Are there any ready made process controllers / deployers for this situation?

What I would like is to have each computer running a simple daemon which connects to a server app that schedules each computer. This server app needs to be able to deploy new applications to run, and schedule how long to let each process run / allow me to manually terminate a job.

I am about to write my own solution so that I can put an end to this manual update process, but I am hoping there is a prebuilt solution.

Platform details - all computers running Windows 7 x64 / Windows Server 2008 x64. All apps are written in .Net 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I worked at SunGard we were doing financial risk calculations using grid computing. We used something by DataSynapse http://www.datasynapse.com/

The code was written in .NET and the platform was similar to yours.

Comment: Interesting - what was the pricing like on this?

Comment: Unfortunately I was a bit too far down the food chain to know stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at implementing Sun Grid Engine (now forked to OGE - http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/) for managing jobs on Slicify.